# How to determine what block isn't covered here?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I have a block of code like this (class/property names have been changed to meet company guidelines):

```
if (output.ExecutionStatus == RuleExecutionStatus.Success &&
    !obj.ListOfObjs.Cast<ConcreteType>().Any(p => p.Id == o.Id))
{
    obj.AddConcreteType(output.ConcreteObj);
}
```

Before adding `&& !obj.ListOfObjs.Cast<ConcreteType>().Any(p => p.Id == o.Id)` this line was 100% covered. I added one test, called `Test 2` down below.

So, after adding the new test, this block is almost 100% covered; but I can't figure out what isn't getting covered. It states `1` block is not covered. The tests executing now have the following attributes:

- Test 1: returns success, has `0` in `ListOfObjs`, no match, adds successfully.
- Test 2: returns success, has `2` in `ListOfObjs`, `1` matches on `Id`, does **not** add.

**What I've Tried**

- Adding a test that has 1 in `ListOfObjs`, no match, adds successfully. I thought maybe the issue was surrounding the fact that it didn't cover the `Any` case where `0` matched.

Comment: What are you using to measure code coverage? Is it the built in VS tool or a third party tool?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, it is the built in VS tool.

Comment: I've found that lambdas cause code coverage tools to "lie" about coverage.  The lambdas generate code that can really never get executed in debug mode and code coverage tools detect that code wasn't executed.  It could simply be something like that.

Comment: Could it be the case where `ListOfObjs` (which presumably is a `List<Interface>`) has a non-`ConcreteType` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't got a test where the execution status *isn't* success - in other words, the first operand of your `&&` expression is `true` for all tests, so you're not checking that it's relevant.

(In general, if you can remove some of your production code without any of your tests breaking, that's a bad sign - or it's a sign that it was non-functional, e.g. an optimization.)